# What is Bouziani space and what are its applications in mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

I have accrossed a new topological space seems were derived from Hilbert Space and it used to solve some boundary value problem for PDE and ODE , Inspired by [this paper](https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2001/21/bouziani.pdf) (page 4, Definition 3.1) , The definition 3.1 talks about Weighted Bouziani space this means that is a well known space which I didn't got it in the web or in wikipedia page , My question :What is Bouziani space and what are its applications in mathematics ?

Comment: No , my interesting is about its application in mathematics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that the ordinary Bouziani space is the space $B^1_2(\Omega)$ discussed in the references [4] and [5] from the paper you cite.

It also seems like Bouziani, who wrote the paper you cite, is in fact the only author who uses the term ``Bouziani space''.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , Since this space is not useful at mathematicians in their research probably means as you said that is ordinary space